# Neo4j - Eager load relationships for a node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a NodeEntity like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedToVia
    private Set<Rel> rels;

    public Rel connectTo(User u, String type) {
        if (this.rels == null) 
            this.rels = new HashSet<Rel>();
        Rel rel = new Rel(this, u, type);
        this.rels.add(rel);
        return rel;
    }
}
```

and the RelationshipEntity:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="REL")
public class Rel {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Fetch
    @StartNode
    private User start;
    @Fetch
    @EndNode
    private User end;

    @RelationshipType
    private String type;

    public Rel(){}
    public Rel(User start, User end, String type) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

but when I try to load the user, the relationships are empty:

```
User neo = new User();
neo.setName("Neo");

User trinity = new User();
trinity.setName("Trinity");
this.userRepository.save(trinity);

neo.connectTo(trinity, "LOVES");

this.userRepository.save(neo);

User user = this.userRepository.findOne(neo.getId());
// expected:<1> but was:<0>
Assert.assertEquals(1, user.getRels().size());
```

Can I eagerly load the relationships related to this node and how, did I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the same relationship type? Your relationship entity gives type="REL", but you pass "LOVES" into neo.connectTo() method.