# Neo4j - Eager load dynamic relationships for a node

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148529/neo4j-eager-load-relationships-for-a-node). I found that everything goes fine for normal relationship entity like this:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="REL")
public class Rel {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Fetch
    @StartNode
    private User start;
    @Fetch
    @EndNode
    private User end;

    public Rel(){}
    public Rel(User start, User end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

but if I add a dynamic relationship type, I cannnot load the relationship eagerly.

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="REL")
public class Rel {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Fetch
    @StartNode
    private User start;
    @Fetch
    @EndNode
    private User end;

    // define dynamic relationship type
    // which cause the issue!!!!
    @RelationshipType
    private String type;

    public Rel(){}
    public Rel(User start, User end, String type) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

What is the issue, and how to solve it?

Any help or advice are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Iterable<UserRelationEntity> rel = template.getRelationshipsBetween(user, client, UserRelationEntity.class, RelTypes.CLIENT.name());
```